# Change post title from <h1> to <h2> in wordpress at single.php

Tags: php, wordpress

i am working on wordpress single.php template this is my code:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>

<?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>

<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

This generates all of the post's data, along with title, content, author and date information. The title of post is wraped in `<h1>` tag, that I need to change into `<h2>` tag. Any help?

This is what I am getting as a result of above code:

```
<article id="post-37" class="post-37 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-home-intro">
                <header class="entry-header">
                                    <h1 class="entry-title">About Us</h1>
                                </header><!-- .entry-header -->

                <div class="entry-content">
            <p>Vivamus condimentum elementum arcu, ac fermentum lectus porttitor sed. Praesent ornare feugiat condimentum. Praesent sagittis metus id magna adipiscing convallis.&nbsp;Vivamus condimentum elementum arcu, ac fermentum lectus porttitor sed. Praesent ornare feugiat condimentum. Praesent sagittis metus id magna adipiscing convallis.&nbsp;Vivamus condimentum elementum arcu, ac fermentum lectus porttitor sed. Praesent ornare feugiat condimentum. Praesent sagittis metus id magna adipiscing convallis.&nbsp;Vivamus condimentum elementum arcu, ac fermentum lectus porttitor sed. Praesent ornare feugiat condimentum. Praesent sagittis metus id magna adipiscing convallis.&nbsp;Vivamus condimentum elementum arcu, ac fermentum lectus porttitor sed. Praesent ornare feugiat condimentum. Praesent sagittis metus id magna adipiscing convallis.&nbsp;Vivamus condimentum elementum arcu, ac fermentum lectus porttitor sed. Praesent ornare feugiat condimentum. Praesent sagittis metus id magna adipiscing convallis.&nbsp;Vivamus condimentum elementum arcu, ac fermentum lectus porttitor sed. Praesent ornare feugiat condimentum. Praesent sagittis metus id magna adipiscing convallis.&nbsp;Vivamus condimentum elementum arcu, ac fermentum lectus porttitor sed. Praesent ornare feugiat condimentum. Praesent sagittis metus id magna adipiscing convallis.</p>
                    </div><!-- .entry-content -->

        <footer class="entry-meta">
            This entry was posted in <a href="http://localhost/?cat=4" title="View all posts in Home Intro" rel="category">Home Intro</a> on <a href="http://localhost/?p=37" title="10:51 am" rel="bookmark"><time class="entry-date" datetime="2013-11-17T10:51:48+00:00">November 17, 2013</time></a><span class="by-author"> by <span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="http://localhost/?author=1" title="View all posts by Engr Zardari" rel="author">Engr Zardari</a></span></span>.                                </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
    </article>
```

Comment: Why? Have you altered the page's hierarchy so that the post title is no longer the top-level header? Or do you just not want to alter the CSS?

Comment: actually i am implementing my own theme, i need `<h2>` instead of `<h1>` to make it the same way as it is in my theme.

Comment: Then you should be altering the CSS, not the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at **content.php**.

There you can change the HTML code corresponding to `get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but changing 
content-page.php
Helped me for changing h1 tags to h2 tags easily. Below is the code.

```
<h2><?phpthe_title();?></h2>

<article class="content-area">
    <?php
    the_post_thumbnail();
          the_content();


    ?>

</article>
```